# Lerch transcendent and harmonic number simplification

Tags: hypergeometric-function, harmonic-numbers

I am trying to find a simplification of the following, preferably to a hypergeometric function. I have the result in Mathematica notation:

```
HarmonicNumber[1 + k] + (-1)^k LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 + k] + Log[2]
```

which I **think** means the following (not sure about the Lerch transcendent):
$$H_{k+1} + (-1)^{k} \Phi (-1, 1, k+2) + \ln(2)$$

I feel like it should be possible to simplify, because evaluating `LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 + k]` for different values of k yields results that contain a $(-1)^{k} \ln(2)$ term.

The reason why I think it should be in terms of a hypergeometric functions, is that I managed to derive analogous results to this one in terms of the pFq fn.

Edit: $k \geq 0$ here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle issue with Wolfram's `LerchPhi`, but for $\Re(2+k) > 0$ it is the same as the standard definition, see [(1)](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/02/). So if $\Re(2+k) > 0 $ you get from [(2)](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.06.03.0020.02)
$$\Phi(-1, 1, k+2) = \frac{1}{k+2}\, {_2}F_1(1,k+2, k+3, -1).$$

According to Maple the RHS can be written  in terms of the digamma function

$$\Phi(-1, 1, k+2) =\frac{1}{2}\Psi\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}k\right)-\frac{1}{2}\Psi\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}k\right),$$
which may be used together with  $H_{k+1} = \Psi(k+2) + \gamma.$

Or you can use a linear transformation  [15.3.4](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_559.htm) from Abramowitz/Stegun 
$$\frac{1}{k+2}\, {_2}F_1(1,k+2, k+3, -1) =\frac{1}{2(k+2)}\, {_2}F_1(1,1, k+3, \tfrac{1}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

I found a simplification by looking at the numbers.

Let

$$a(k)=H_{k+1}+(-1)^k \phi (-1,1,k+2)+\log (2)$$

Then the first 10 terms (starting from k=0) are

$$\left\{2,2,\frac{8}{3},\frac{8}{3},\frac{46}{15},\frac{46}{15},\frac{352}{105},\frac{352}{105},\frac{1126}{315},\frac{1126}{315}\right\}$$

The sequence is "repetitive", i.e.

$$a(2k) = a(2k+1), k=0, 1, 2, ...$$

Furthermore, from the values we deduce (with the help of OEIS or otherwise) that

$$a(2k) = 2\sum _{i=1}^{2k} \frac{1}{2 i-1}$$

which is the harmonic partial sum of odd terms.

Hence for the (nontrivial) even terms the simplification is simply given in terms of Harmonic numbers

$$a(2k) = 2 H_{2 k+1}-H_k$$